# How to reorder CSV columns in Apache NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

Reorder column in a csv in apache nifi.

**Input** - I have multiple files which have same columns but are in different order.

**Output** - Scrape some columns and store in same order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, because I'm sure those columns will be included in all CSV files, I just need to reorder them. So I use `QueryRecord` to reorder my csv files.

For example, here're my csv files:

```
\\file1
name, age, location, gender
Jack, 40, TW, M
Lisa, 30, CA, F 

\\file2
name, location, gender, age
Mary, JP, F, 25
Kate, DE, F, 23
```

I'd like to reorder columns to `location,name,gender,age`, I set a new property in `QueryRecord` named `reorder_data`, with the value like:

`SELECT location,name,gender,age FROM FLOWFILE`

Then data in the flowfile will become:

```
\\file1 - reordered
location, name, gender, age
TW, Jack, M, 40
CA, Lisa, F, 30

\\file2 - reordered
location, name, gender, age
JP, Mary, F, 25
DE, Kate, F, 23
```

Thus, I can get reordered data output from `QueryRecord` as well as original data, it's very convenient.

BTW, You can also use group variable or attribute to set column order for better maintenance:

```
//Group variable or attribute
column_order   location,name,gender,age

//Property in QueryRecord
reorder_data   SELECT ${column_order} FROM FLOWFILE
```

Comment: Convert record is an easy way to do it. You can add schemas on updateattribute specific to your input file and add a common output schema. But Query record also works like charm. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with ConvertRecord, you'd have the schema for the CSVRecordReader match the columns (in order) of the input, and the output schema for the CSVRecordSetWriter would have the schema with the selected columns in the desired output order. I haven't tried this but I believe that's how it works.

Comment: It works. Thanks!! ConvertRecord and QueryRecord both of them work.
All that has to be done is create an input and output Avro schema in a schema registery.