# Apache NiFi: Extracting nth column from a csv

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a csv with many columns. I want to get the 6th column out of 10 columns. I have tried [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58182118/how-to-reorder-csv-columns-in-apache-nifi). But this won't answer my question since its used to extract the first column.

```
123,456,2,34,78,678,456,88,45,123
```

The answer should be 678. How is this possible. Suggest the flow and necessary processors that must be used.